# MySQL query returns row 0 when it doesn't match the query criteria

Tags: php, mysql, select, primary-key, record

I have a table with a primary key:

Type:INT Length:11 Default:NULL Extra:auto_increment

The table contains 3 records - 0, 1 and 4

When I try...

```
SELECT the_key FROM the_table WHERE the_key='someRandomString'
```

...it returns 1 record (primary key 0)

I can solve it with a PHP is_numeric() but why doesn't it return 0 records?

Comment: what are you using a string on to equal a number ?

Comment: It's a project-based app. I'm getting a project id from the query string and checking to see if the project exists or not. Don't worry, I'm doing it more safely. The example has been simplified. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're comparing an int column against a string value? It looks like MySQL is converting the string to an int, coming up with 0, and matching that row.

Two options:

1. Don't do that. Don't write comparisons of incompatible types.
2. See if MySQL has an option to go into a stricter mode where it doesn't convert incompatible types automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm afraid I do need to check the query string against the primary key. It would be great if there was some PHP or MySQL solution that I could put in the page rather than changing the database settings.

Comment: If your primary key is auto_incrementing, start it at 1, not zero. Zero is a questionable value for an ID, since it has special meaning in various contexts (e.g. false, null).

Comment: Comparing a string to a number is a bad idea.  You *should* call intval() on your values before using them in your query, and you should not enclose that value in quotes (strings go in quotes, numbers do not).

Comment: Really should be using bound parameters, never concatenating user-supplied data into SQL.

Comment: Found another way to query the DB. Lots of helpful points here. Thanks!